# What is this reptile/lizard?

Tags: reptiles, lizards

Can anyone please tell me what this is? I am thinking its either a gila monster or a monitor, but could be completely wrong.
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about identifying an animal species. Biology-SE has more expertise for the task.

Comment: Have you asked on the biology site?

Comment: Do you have any other pictures? More of the head would be nice. How big is it right now?

Comment: Off topic per http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/410/should-we-discourage-pet-breed-species-identification-questions

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely not a Gila Monster, as you can see an example of below.

[image: Gila Monster]
<sup>([Source](http://www.conservation.org/FMG/Articles/Pages/gila_monsters_human_health_mexico.aspx))</sup>

It would definitely help me be sure of what type of monitor it is, if you provided more information. What size the is monitor right now, where you got it from, more pictures. Anything more would be useful.

From what I can tell, it looks to me like you have a [Lace Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lace_monitor). They tend to have that skinny head, compared to other lizards of that size. As well as those distinctive bands. Other monitors tend to be speckled.

Here is a picture of a young Lace Monitor for reference:

[image: Young Lace Monitor] 
<sup>([Source](http://www.sareptiles.co.za/forum/viewtopic.php?f=121&t=348))</sup>